# jQuery Kendo Grid calling a function from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

**Background:** I am attempting to work on a grid where one column can have different editor based on the column value in a Grid. I found a working [example](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/knowledge-base/grid-different-editor-based-on-column-value) on Telerik site. It works great!

**Issue:** I like to separate out html code in html file vs jquery code in js file. Once I separated out the code like this I am getting an error which says "customTemplate is not defined". customTemplate is a function which is being called from *template* under field *editor*. I also created a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/husy0ctr/) of what my code looks like locally where i seem to be getting same error.

I think the problem is around template attribute where I am calling the customTemplate function. I tried swapping the double quotes to single quotes and that didn't seem to work either.

Below is how grid and customTemplate function is defined:

```
   $("#grid").kendoGrid({
      dataSource: dataSource,
      columns: [
        { field: "id" , title: "ID" },
        { field:"type" , title: "Type" },
        { field: "editor",
          title: "Editor",
           template: "#=customTemplate(data.type,data.editor)#",
          editor: chooseEditor
        }],
      editable: true
    });
  });

 function customTemplate(type,value) {
    if (value == null)
      return "";

    switch (type) {
      case "date":
        return kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(value), 'yyyy/MM/dd');
      default:
        return value;
    }
  }
```

[image: Here is the screenshot of the ReferenceError I get]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a function to call your function instead of a template string:

```js
{
  field: 'editor',
  title: 'Editor',
  template: function(dataItem) {
    return customTemplate(dataItem.type, dataItem.editor);
  },
  editor: chooseEditor
}
```

Fiddle: https://dojo.telerik.com/AluziYAc

Comment: thanks ! that worked like charm!!

Comment: Should we only use template string to call our function when putting this code in html file?

Comment: @HereToLearn_ - Typically the only time I use template Strings is when I want to do simple formatting. e.g. date formatting (when the field is defined as a date in the datasource's schema) can be done using: `template: '{0: yyyy/mm/dd}'` edit - actually, that is the format tab. Come to think of it I don't think I've ever used a template string in the grid column, I've always used a function.